# problemas con notificaciones

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Hice una app en android studio, la cual utiliza notificaciones, la app la instale en un equipo que tiene android 7, la app funciona perfectamente y las notificaciones suenan y aparecen en la barra superior.

Instale la app en un equipo con android 10, todo funciona menos las notificaciones, probe en un equipo con android 9 y tampoco funcionan las notificaciones, revise los permisos de notificaciones en ambos equipos, todo esta habilitado para que aparezcan y suenen, pero aun asi no suenan ni aparecen en la barra superior.

Hasta donde he leido y revisado la documentacion de android, no se necesita permiso alguno en el AndroidManifest.xml, para que funcionen las notificaciones. ¿Me falta algun permiso?

Me colaboran por favor, gracias

Este es el codigo que uso para las notificaciones.

```
private void recordatorio_tareas() {


          NotificationManager nManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

          Intent intent = new Intent(recordatorio.this, MainActivity.class);
          intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
          PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(recordatorio.this, 0, intent, 0);

          int color = 0x00FF00;

          String mensaje1 = "Recordatorio";
          String mensaje2 = "No olviden trabajar en la manualidad que deben presentar la proxima semana.";

          NotificationCompat.Builder notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                getBaseContext())
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.barney_icono1))
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.barney_icono2)
                .setContentTitle(mensaje1)
                .setContentText(mensaje2)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(mensaje2))
                .setColor(color)
                .setWhen( System.currentTimeMillis() )
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(Uri.parse("android.resourse://" + "/" + R.raw.barney_sonido));

            nManager.notify(3, notification.build());

}
```

Comment: Hola, recuerda agregar lo que trataste o investigaste por favor, revisa [ask],saludos.

Comment: Hola Elenasys, ya coloque el codigo de la notificacion que uso. gracias

Comment: Gracias @Isabel, revisa mi respuesta ahí comento cual es el problema por el cual no recibes las notificaciones en ciertos sistemas operativos.

Comment: Hola @Elenasys, gracias, ya lei la documentacion y corregi el codigo para que las notificaciones aparezcan, sin embargo hay algo que no he logrado que me funcione, me puedes colaborar por favor.  EL sonido por defecto que ofrece la notificacion suena, pero cuando personalizo el sonido, no suena. El codigo que uso para personalizar el sonido es este. .setSound(Uri.parse("android.resourse://" + "/" + R.raw.barney_sonido));             el sonido lo tengo en la carpeta raw.   Gracias

Comment: Hola @Isabel también hay cambios para los sonidos, si quieres realiza otra pregunta con la información que tienes para ayudarte! :D

Comment: @Elenasys, ok voy hacer la nueva pregunta gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gracias a que agregaste tu código se puede ver cual es el problema. Comentas que en Android 7 funcionan la notificaciones pero en Android 10 no se reciben.

**El problema se debe a que no estas asignando un "canal", a partir de Android 8.0 (API nivel 26), todas las notificaciones deben asignarse a un canal. En cada canal, puedes configurar el comportamiento visual y auditivo que se aplicará a todas las notificaciones de este.**

Define un nombre del canal  este asignalo al crear la notificación:

```
...
...
String canal = "notificaciones Isabel";
NotificationCompat.Builder notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                getBaseContext(), canal)
...
...
```

Si tu app la creas con un `targetSdkVersion` posterior a 26, lo cual es lo más seguro, necseitas agregar el canal.

Revisa:

[**Cómo crear y administrar canales de notificaciones**](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels)